# Is RequestMapping not multithreaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a RequestMapping listening web request in my controller, and whenever someone visits my webpage, it will delay the response 5000 milliseconds.

Everything works fine, but when I visit again with a new tab in Chrome at the same time, the second request ends up being delayed 10000 milliseconds. This confuses me, is Spring MVC not multithreaded? Can someone tell me what happened here?

```
@RequestMapping("/view")
@ResponseBody

public String View() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return "done";
}
```

**EDIT**
My spring boot version is 1.2.7.RELEASE.
dependencies : spring-boot-starter-web

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

You opened new tab in a session, it might cause a problem with synchronization.
While you will look in Spring Docs, you will find:
`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.setSynchronizeOnSession(boolean)` which synchronizes every controller on a session mutex. This might be overkill for your application. But it makes at least controllers thread safe on the session without blocking other user.

Hope, it will help.

Comment: Hi m.aibin ,thanks for your reply, i follow this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705024/adding-session-synchronization-to-spring-mvc/21738309#21738309) to modify the SynchronizeOnSession property. and i find the default value is false, is it mean my process is under Asynchronous ? If i set the SynchronizeOnSession to true , the results did not change.I used the wrong way?